# How to hide Geo tag to appear in vcard but still making available it fot google bot

Tags: hide, microdata, hcard

```
<div class="vcard" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
     <strong class="fn org" itemprop="name">Commercial Office Bangalore</strong><br/>
              <span class="adr" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="httep:schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <span class="street-address"itemprop="streetAddress">330, Raheja Arcade, 1/1 Koramangala Industrial Layout</span><br/>  
                   <span class="locality"itemprop="addressLocality">Bangalore</span>
                     <span itemprop="postalCode"class="postal-code">560095</span><br/>
                      <span class="region"itemprop="addressRegion">Karnataka</span><br/>
                     <span class="country-name">India</span><br/>
                  <span class="tel id"="phone"itemprop="telephone">+91-80-41101360</span><br/>
                <span class="geo"itemprop="geo"itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCordinates">
              <abbr class="latitude" property="latitude">12.936504</abbr>
            <abbr class="longitude" property="longitude">77.6321344</abbr>
         <meta itemprop="latitude" content="12.936504" />
       <meta itemprop="longitude" content="77.6321344" />
   </span>
 </span>
```

I want to make lat and  logitude invisible for user and visible for Google bot. What shall I do?

Comment: Set the color of your latitude and longitude fields to the page background color, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

#### If you mean the Microdata (using Schema.org):

Just remove the `abbr` elements. You are already giving this data in `meta` elements (which [can be used in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)), which is the correct way to provide data that should/can not be visible on the page:

```html
<meta itemprop="latitude" content="12.936504" />
<meta itemprop="longitude" content="77.6321344" />
```

(Note that you were using `property` attributes, but they are not allowed in Microdata, only in RDFa.)

(Also note that you use `http://schema.org/GeoCordinates` but it should be `http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates`. And `httep:schema.org/PostalAddress` is also wrong.)

#### If you mean the Microformat (using hCard):

You could reuse the `meta` elements used with Microdata:

```html
<meta class="latitude" itemprop="latitude" content="12.936504" />
<meta class="longitude" itemprop="longitude" content="77.6321344" />
```

But I’m not sure if all Microformat parsers support this.

Comment: @albert: This HTML is not invalid.

Comment: indeed it is not valid. he meant the hcard .geo class. still wouldn't be valid

Answer (score 0):

The `abbr` elements with lat and lon can be set to  `display:none`, which does exactly what you are asking for, hiding the content from humans, while still serving it up to bots:

```
abbr{display:none}  
/** or **/
.latitude,
.longitude{display:none}
```

Although I can't honestly see what's wrapping them in your example. Ff the `span` with class `.geo` is the parent element, you could make that `display:none` instead.